# curl returns blank from valid url

Tags: curl, url

I am trying to lookup a zipcode from usps using curl like so:

```
curl "https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=11111&zip="
```

This url does return normal output from browser.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to specify the `User-Agent` header (using the `-A` option) so that the request resembles a request from a browser. Also, due to the presence of `!` in the URL, one has to use `'` instead of `"`:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0" \ 
    'https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=10001&zip='
```